# error while starting Titan database using docker

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, cassandra, titan

I want to start using titan database and I have followed http://oren.github.io/blog/titan.html instructions. But when I try to start titan in docker it gives me the following error:

```
/opt/titan-0.5.4-hadoop2/run.sh: 2: /opt/titan-0.5.4-hadoop2/run.sh:  : not found
```

run.sh file located in C:\Users\Modeso\titan but I can't find a way to change the folder location in docker.

Has anyone faced this problem before or have solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that in this case, the "not found" message may not be because the file is not found, but because the wrong line-endings are used in the file. If a shell-script uses Windows line-endings, Linux can produce weird errors, such as this one.

Did you try building from the GitHub repository? https://github.com/apobbati/titan-rexster

You can build an image from that repository through;

```
docker build -t titan-rexter github.com/apobbati/titan-rexster
```

And run it;